# Upgrading from 4.4 to 4.6 stalls - Wordpress

Tags: upgrade, error

I'm trying to update civicrm from version 4.4 to 4.6.   When I try to run the update script, it stalls at "Executed: Upgrade DB to 4.5.beta2"

I found this similar post for drupal (https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=26648.0) but the answer that worked for him won't work for me.  I checked and this code is already there in civicrm.settings.php:

```
require_once 'CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php';
CRM_Core_ClassLoader::singleton()->register();
```

I risked refreshing the page once, and it actually kept going a little bit further to this point: [Executed: Upgrade DB to 4.5.beta9: SQL]

Looking at my inspect element console, I see this ajax warning:

http://mydevurl.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js (9664)

```
POST http://mydevurl.com/wp-admin/admin.php?   page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade/queue/ajax/runNext 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery.js:9664
m.extend.ajax @ jquery.js:9215
runNext @ admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fupgrade%2Fqueue%2Frunner&reset=1&qrid=CRM_Upgrade:687
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I found this post after having an upgrade from 4.2. to 4.6.11 freeze on me when it got to the first 4.6.x upgrade script. I tried refreshing the screen and it continued to the end, fortunately. That said, upgrading in smaller steps make eminent sense; that was going to be my next move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally resolved this issue by hiring an expert who updated the CiviCRM database on a different server.  There was a conflict with the web hosting.

Answer (score 2):

Try running the upgrades more incrementally (e.g. update to 4.4.20, then to 4.5, then 4.6, etc). (I've had the upgrade process stall on me when trying to move more than a handful of versions at a time.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to upgrade from civicrm 4.4 to 4.6. Try to do it in steps (4.4 -> 4.5 -> 4.6).